# .NET Core 3 ignore property when serializing to JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to ignore a property when returning JSON in an ActionResult.
I've found that `[IgnoreDataMember]` or `[JsonIgnore]` should work, but they have no affect for me.

**ActionResult:**

```
[HttpGet("categories")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Categories()
{
    var categories = await _marketService.GetCategoriesAsync();
    return Json(categories.OrderBy(i => i.SortOrder));
}
```

**Class**

```
public class MarketCategory
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    public string UrlSlug { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string ScrapeUrl { get; set; }
}
```

I've also tried the following on my class, trying to just only include the "Id" property, however, my ActionResult still returns the full object with all of its properties:

```
[DataContract]
public class MarketCategory
{
    [DataMember]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    public string UrlSlug { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public string ScrapeUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks in advance.